# How can I count a loop within a rendered partial?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, loops, ruby-on-rails-4, counter

I have a List model and a ListItem model.

In lists/show I have some code, then I call

```
=render @list.list_items
```

In my list_items/list_item partial, I have a loop that runs if a condition is exists:

```
-if condition.exists?
   output
-else
   output something else
```

What I want to do is put a counter inside the `if condition.exists?` so that I can know how many times the condition exists. Then, back in the lists/show view, I'd like to be able to tell the user the `condition.exists?.count` vs. the total `@list.list_items.count` at the top of the page.

I am not sure how to set up the counter inside of the if loop of the rendered partial. I know that `render @list.list_items` should create a `list_item_counter', but I only want a counter for the times the condition within the rendered partial exists. Is there a way to trick the`list_item_counter` to function like this?

I am also unsure of how I could access this condition counter inside of the lists/show view, since I would need to have the `render @list.list_items` complete, then pass the counter value back to @list somehow.

I'd really appreciate any advice, as I am stumped.

Comment: You should be able to call `list_item_counter` in your partial to get an index of current item..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do what you want with the built-in Rails partial iterator, there is a counter provided by Rails, it'll be called `list_item_counter` for your partial, but it will always increment once per iteration, you can't increment it conditionally.

To do what you want you'll need to create your own iterator, maybe something like this:

```
- counter = 0
- @list.list_items.each do |item|
  - if condition.exists?
    - partial = "item"
    - counter += 1
  - else
    - partial = "other_partial"
  = render partial: partial, object: item, locals: { counter: counter }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I put `=list_item_counter` inside the `if condition.exists?`, but the list_item_counter still counts for each time the `@list.list_items` partial renders a list_item. If I have four total list_items and the first and third have conditions, `=list_item_counter` is giving me 0 and 2. I think that is how it is supposed to work, but please let me know if I am doing that incorrectly.

Comment: That's precisely how it's supposed to work, it is incremented once for each iteration, sorry I missed your requirement about tracking on that condition, I've fixed my answer.

Comment: It is so frustrating when you see the answer to one of your questions and you are just like, "duh! why didn't I think of that?" Thank you very much for your help. Your updated response was exactly what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome. It can be hard to abandon a really nice helper, and there are so many little tricks in Rails it's still a reasonable question.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
cnt = 0
-if condition.exists?
   output
   cnt += 1
-else
   output something else
```

then `cnt` will be your **counter**

Comment: That won't work in his partial because `cnt=0` will be set on each iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I originally had the same thought as you and tried this, but smathy is right, the counter resets at each iteration of the partial.